# special condition query for mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks for emails of people who have completed a task where completed tasks = 1 and not completed = 0. The email is in table jos_users and the tasks table name is keyperson. The keyperson table has user id and task field titled "check1".

The issue is that some users have more than one check1 task which is represented as multiple rows in the keyperson table. So this query does not work since it does not take into account that some users may have a row where check1 = 1 AND more check1 rows where check1 = 0.

```
select DISTINCT(u.email) as email 
from jos_users u, keyperson k
where k.kp1 = u.id and k.check1 = 1
```

That query will find everyone who has completed at least 1 check1 task, but I need to find the ones who have completed ALL of their check1 tasks.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT isn't a function.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try grouping by email and checking that `max(check) = min(check) = 1`

```
select u.email
from jos_users u join keyperson k on k.kp1 = u.id
group by u.email
having max(k.check1) = 1 and min(k.check1) = 1
```